# Predicting cluster of a new object with kmeans in R

Tags: clustering

I used my training dataset to fit cluster using kmenas function

```
fit <- kmeans(ca.data, 2);
```

How can I use fit object to predict cluster membership in a new dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of your options is to use [cl_predict](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/clue/html/predict.html) from the `clue`package (note: I found this through googling "kmeans R predict").

Comment: Link didn't work for me, instead I used this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clue/versions/0.3-57/topics/cl_predict

Answer (score 6):

Check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78322/is-there-a-function-in-r-that-takes-the-centers-of-clusters-that-were-found-and) complete answer.
The code you need is:

```
clusters <- function(x, centers) {
  # compute squared euclidean distance from each sample to each cluster center
  tmp <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)),
                function(i) apply(centers, 1,
                                  function(v) sum((x[i, ]-v)^2)))
  max.col(-t(tmp))  # find index of min distance
}

# create a simple data set with two clusters
set.seed(1)
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
x_new <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(10, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
               matrix(rnorm(10, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x_new) <- c("x", "y")

cl <- kmeans(x, centers=2)

all.equal(cl[["cluster"]], clusters(x, cl[["centers"]]))
# [1] TRUE
clusters(x_new, cl[["centers"]])
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: It's been a while from my answer; now I recommend to build a predictive model (like the random forest), using the cluster variable as the target. I got better results in practice with this approach. For example, in clustering all variables are equally important, while the predictive model can automatically choose the ones that maximize the prediction of the cluster. This approach is also compatible with the deployment on production (i.e. predicting to which cluster the case belongs).

Answer (score 4):

You could write an S3 method to predict the classes for a new dataset. The following minimises the sum-of-squares. It is used as for other `predict` functions: `newdata` should match the structure of your input to kmeans, and the `method` argument should work as for `fitted.kmeans`

```
predict.kmeans <- function(object,
                           newdata,
                           method = c("centers", "classes")) {
  method <- match.arg(method)

  centers <- object$centers
  ss_by_center <- apply(centers, 1, function(x) {
    colSums((t(newdata) - x) ^ 2)
  })
  best_clusters <- apply(ss_by_center, 1, which.min)
  
  if (method == "centers") {
    centers[best_clusters, ]
  } else {
    best_clusters
  }
}
```

I wish there was a `predict.kmeans` in the existing `stats` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the predict method from [flexclust](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexclust/index.html) package after converting your `stats::kmeans` model to his `kcca` type.