# machine learning to predict probability distributions

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, classification

Is there a way that, given a sample set of random values, using machine learning techniques one can be able to predict its probability distribution. 
What I mean is that, if I generate different sample sets, each drawn from different distributions, i.e. weibull, gamma, exp or lognormal, I can use these sets as training ones and then feeding some new data sets I would be able to find out their distribution as the best fit(if they fall into one of the above) ?

It would be very helpful if anyone could indicate anyway how to achieve this.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12623/predicting-cluster-of-a-new-object-with-kmeans-in-r